# Ruby On Rails Subdomain Convention

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, subdomain

I have a domain, *domain.com*, and I want one Rails application, for example, to handle all subdomain requests, i.e., *blog.domain.com*, *subdomain.domain.com*, etc.

The Ruby on Rails framework is all about convention.  So, is there a convention for creating subdomains in Rails?  If so, what is it?  If not, what might be some good methods for trying to get what I described above accomplished?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could follow this tutorial on using subdomains in Rails:
http://railsapps.github.io/tutorial-rails-subdomains.html

Basically, you implement routing for subdomains like this:

```
match '/' => 'profiles#show', :constraints => { :subdomain => /.+/ }
```

Url helper methods also accepts a subdomain option so you can write url helpers like:

```
link_to root_url(:subdomain => user.name), root_url(:subdomain => user.name)
```

You'll find more details as to how to use subdomains in the link provided above.